# How can I add comma on a price slider value

Tags: jquery

I've complete a price range using jquery. But I can't add comma on its value 
Please see the image and help enter image description here. Here is my code

I need like the second one
[image]

```js
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 250000,
            max: 2000000,
            values: [ 250000, 2000000 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " to $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " to $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " to $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

to

```
  $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") +
            " to $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
```

and

```
$("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " to $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
```

to:

```
$("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + " to $" + ui.values[1].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
```