# Javascript - Add comma separator to thousands number

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I am using the jquery ui range slider.
Trying to add comma to the numbers so it will bore readable.
tried like yo different ways including [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808773/add-comma-separator-to-a-value-variable) and `parseFloat`but without success.

this is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davseveloff/L01900xc/).

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778519/how-can-i-add-comma-on-a-price-slider-value

Comment: you want comma seprate value ???

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want ?
https://jsfiddle.net/sxd60y6x/

```
NUMBER.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
```

See : [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: the output for `1.00000` is `1.00,000` which is incorrect.

Comment: Indeed but look at the requirement of the user. He has not this input.We do not test the number in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method.

Here is how your code should look like.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 10000,
    max: 10000000,
    values: [1000000, 4000000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var minVal = ui.values[0].toLocaleString();
        var maxVal = ui.values[1].toLocaleString();
        $("#amount").val("₪" + minVal + " - ₪" + maxVal);
    }
});
```

And you need to do the same to your initial value code.

```
$("#amount").val("₪" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0).toLocaleString() + " - ₪" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1).toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Thank you! I have bee breaking my head with this for a few hours... How do I add commas to the `slider.min` and `slider.max` initial values? t

Comment: @DavSev you need to do the same to your initial value code. I have edited my post to include it.